# Laravel - check for string before another string

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a Laravel where clause in which I check if a column contains a certain string 
`->where('column_name', 'like', '%{string}%')`. I want to update it so I can look for this string before a certain word is in the column. So if I have in the column: "This is dog but this is new dog." I have 2  occurrences of dog and I want the first one before the word new.

Comment: What do you mean you `want the first one`. What you're showing us is a `where` clause, not a `select` clause. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Well yes because in the where I select the string - for the example "dog" but I want "dog" before the "new" string. Not sure I need select here since they are in the same column.

Comment: What's the difference between selecting "dog" and "dog"?

Comment: The difference is that the first dog is before "new" and the second dog is after "new".

Comment: Can you please provide an example of updates you are trying to achieve? We want to help you but it's not clear what you exactly want 

Comment: @ChristopheHubert don't really know what to say more in order to make it more clear. I want to select the first occurrence of a string in a column before a specific word.

Comment: What I mean is what are you trying to achieve by finding the first occurrence of a given string - what does that bring you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is normally done using regex
2. If it is possible to get the query result and do a regex, that would be better
3. I can give you two links that can help you [Laravel raw queries](https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) and [MySQL regexp](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-regexp-function.php)

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you are looking for two words that appear in the column and precede each other. If that's the case, you can concatenate the two strings like so

```
->where('column_name', 'like', '%{firstString} {string}%')
```

Comment: Sadly that's not quite the case as they may not be directly one after another.